# Auto tag files as UTF-8

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I am using Visual SourceSafe 6.0. We've been given the green light to move forward to Visual SourceSafe 2005. Still way out of date, but I'll take it.

In VSS 6.0 we had options of Text/Binary for files. In VSS 2005 these correspond to ANSI/Binary and were mapped automatically. However I notice there are new options for Unicode support.

What I want is to change my files to be Unicode (UTF-8) instead of ANSI. But the command line tool only seems to have the original two options: Text/Binary. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181101(v=vs.80).aspx)

How can I get the files to be correct? Do I need to manually open properties for each one? I have nearly 3000 files in some projects. So a script/batch file seems the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure batch job is the only way to go. 
I doubt VSS has the ability to do such thing.

So you will need to checked out all files. modify the properties and check it back in.